# Oracle unique contraint with replace function

Tags: oracle, constraints

I'm not sure if this is possible but I wanted to ask the community.

I have a column with file names that users have uploaded to my site.  I want to create a unique constraint that will remove all the blanks from the filename column so even if the user makes a mistake and adds an extra space the constraint will throw an error.

I thought about creating a new column within my table and removing all spaces when I insert the filename, but I wanted to see if this can be done on the fly.

I'm thinking the performance will take a major hit and if so I will create the new column within my table.  Is there a better way to check if a filename is in my table and somewhat encompass some simple mistakes that users make to catch duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique function-based index. Here is an example:

```
create table test_table (
  filename varchar2(50)
)
/

create unique index test_table_filename_idx on test_table(replace(filename, ' ', null))
/

insert into test_table (filename) values ('abc')
/

insert into test_table (filename) values ('a b c')
/
```

Because of the function-based index, that 2nd insert produces the expected error of:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.TEST_TABLE_FILENAME_IDX) violated

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: sstan, What if there is an ID along with the file name as the constraint.  There can be the same title when the ID is different.  THX

Comment: I don't completely understand your concern. Why would you want to have `ID` in the same constraint as `file name`? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: This is an event and there is an event id that goes along with the titles of the files that users will upload.  So the same title can appear for multiple events, but not the same one.    I just figured it out by putting ID right before the filename.  create unique index test_table_filename_idx on test_table(ID, replace(filename, ' ', null))
/